# Creating week flags from DOW

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
    DOW
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
```

This corresponds to the dayof the week. Now I want to create this dataframe-

```
   DOW MON_FLAG TUE_FLAG    WED_FLAG    THUR_FLAG   FRI_FLAG    SAT_FLAG
0   0   0        0          0             0            0           0
1   1   1        0          0             0            0           0
2   2   0        1          0             0            0           0
3   3   0        0          1             0            0           0
4   4   0        0          0             1            0           0
5   5   0        0          0             0            1           0
6   6   0        0          0             0            0           1
7   0   0        0          0             0            0           0
8   1   1        0          0             0            0           0
```

Depending on the DOW column for example its 1 then MON_FLAG will be 1 if its 2 then TUES_FLAG will be 1 and so on. I have kept Sunday as 0 that's why all the flag columns are zero in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `rename` columns by dictionary:

```
d = {0:'SUN_FLAG',1:'MON_FLAG',2:'TUE_FLAG',
     3:'WED_FLAG',4:'THUR_FLAG',5: 'FRI_FLAG',6:'SAT_FLAG'}
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['DOW']).rename(columns=d))
print (df)
   DOW  SUN_FLAG  MON_FLAG  TUE_FLAG  WED_FLAG  THUR_FLAG  FRI_FLAG  SAT_FLAG
0    0         1         0         0         0          0         0         0
1    1         0         1         0         0          0         0         0
2    2         0         0         1         0          0         0         0
3    3         0         0         0         1          0         0         0
4    4         0         0         0         0          1         0         0
5    5         0         0         0         0          0         1         0
6    6         0         0         0         0          0         0         1
7    0         1         0         0         0          0         0         0
8    1         0         1         0         0          0         0         0
```